# Por que o Data Annotation não reconhece o DateTime?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, datetime

A view não está reconhecendo a data no formado {dd MM yyyy},ex:31/12/2020 . Já estou quebrando cabeça por horas.

[image: View Razor]

```
        *[Required]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        [Column(TypeName = "DateTime2")]
        [Display(Name = "Data de Início")]
        public DateTime DataInicio { get; set; }*
```

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DataInicio , new { @class = "data form-control" })
```

Comment: *DisplayFormat* isso é o formato para exibição, a data é tratada conforme a cultura. Para evitar isso uma opção é usar o tipo `string` e validar o formato quando recebe a model na action

Comment: A questão que tanto o TextBoxFor quanto EditorFor está lendo no formado MM dd yyyy. Não estou entendendo isso. ex: 12/31/2020 OK.

Comment: acho que está tendo um erro de intepretação ai... esses atributos são usados para renderizar o elemento no navegador, exibindo a data no formato correto, podendo renderizar como `input` no *type* correto (text, date, etc). Quando vai fazer o post, e isso precisa ser convertido para o model que é recebida na action, ai estamos falando de código `.net` e a data tem de ser convertida para o formato que o server vai entender. Se o culture estiver mm/dd/aaaa, é nesse formato que precisa ser postando, ou seja, para o post o que há no input deve poder ser feito parse para o tipo da model.